# How to apply function to a table in parallel and store the results - R

Tags: r, parallel.foreach, doparallel

I'm trying to go through all the rows from a table to apply some functions. Something like:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
   df[i,2] <- somefunction1(df[i,1])
   df[i,3] <- somefunction2(df[i,1])
   df[i,3] <- somefunction3(df[i,1])
   df[i,4] <- somefunction4(df[i,1])
}
```

This works but it takes too long so I was thinking in parallelization with the library *doParallel*. But when I try:

```
foreach(i = 1:nrow(df) ) %dopar% {
   df[i,2] <- somefunction1(df[i,1])
   df[i,3] <- somefunction2(df[i,1])
   df[i,3] <- somefunction3(df[i,1])
   df[i,4] <- somefunction4(df[i,1])}
```

It doesn't change the table, but it returns a list with the last function results.

I guess maybe this is not the best approach for what I want to achieve so I am open to receive new ways to make this kind of code more efficient. This is something that an excel table makes automatically to all the cells at the same time without spending so much time, so I think R should be able to do this somehow.

If parallelization is the way to go, I would like to receive some orientation about how to store the results in the table directly inside the loop, without executing each function separatedly and store it after that (it makes the code slow and less reliable with the association of the results to the variables).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That's a really inefficient way to perform a function on every row in the data frame.  Do you have to use a for loop at all?

Here is some code that runs some simple functions on row in the data frame, in parallel:

```
a <- sample(1:1000)

df <- as.data.frame(cbind(a))

somefunction1 <- function(x) {
  x/1
}

somefunction2 <- function(x) {
  x/2
}

somefunction3 <- function(x) {
  x/3
}

somefunction4 <- function(x) {
  x/4
}

for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  df[i,1] <- somefunction1(df[i,1])
  df[i,2] <- somefunction2(df[i,1])
  df[i,3] <- somefunction3(df[i,1])
  df[i,4] <- somefunction4(df[i,1])
}

library(foreach)
library(doMC)
library(abind)

registerDoMC(detectCores()-1)

acomb <- function(...) abind(..., along=1)

par_df <- foreach(i=icount(nrow(df)), .combine='acomb', .multicombine=TRUE) 
%dopar%
{

  df[i,1] <- somefunction1(df[i,1])
  df[i,2] <- somefunction2(df[i,1])
  df[i,3] <- somefunction3(df[i,1])
  df[i,4] <- somefunction4(df[i,1])

  df[i,]

}

par_df_2 <- data.frame(par_df, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

*This is not an issue with parallelization.*

Your code between `{ }` behaves like a function would. See the following example

```
myfun <- function() {
   1
   2
   3
}

myfun()
# 3
```

There is an implicit `return` of the last evaluated value, and the other evaluated values are lost. The same is occurring with your "function"

```
foreach(i = 1:nrow(df) ) %dopar% {
  df[i,2] <- somefunction1(df[i,1])
  df[i,3] <- somefunction2(df[i,1])
  df[i,3] <- somefunction3(df[i,1])
  df[i,4] <- somefunction4(df[i,1])}
```

You can modify it as

```
foreach(i = 1:nrow(df) ) %dopar% {
  c(somefunction1(df[i,1]), somefunction2(df[i,1]), somefunction3(df[i,1]), somefunction4(df[i,1])) }
```

to return a vector of the evaluated values

---

Second, and arguably more important, you should try to change your functions to accept vectors and return vectors. So instead of

```
df[i,2] <- somefunction1(df[i,1])   # single element in vector
```

Try

```
df[,2] <- somefunction1(df[,1])     # entire vector
```